# .NET Provide F1 help to big application

Tags: .net, winforms

how can i provide F1 help support to .Net application.

the application consist of several form with many fields. so i dont want to drop HelpProvider control on each form and set the properties. 
please tell me any component that can handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you could implement a class that inherits Form and adds a HelpProvider, then inherit your forms from that class. That way, you'd only have to set the properties

Form -> AppFormBase -> ConcreteForm

```
Public Class AppFormBase
  Inherits Form ' Your original base class

  Public Sub New()
    ' Add HelpProvider to Me.Controls
  End Sub
End Class

Public Class MyActualForm ' Your original form.
  Inherits AppFormBase

End Class
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know this framework. If you look at what your forms currently inherit from, you may be able to change that into a class of your own, which inherits from the original base class of your form.

Example added to answer.

Answer (score 0):

For **WPF**, you may do the following:

```
CommandBinding HelpBinding = new CommandBinding(
            ApplicationCommands.Help,
            ShowHelpHandler,
            CanShowHelpHandler);
CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding(typeof(Window), HelpBinding);
```

where `ShowHelpHandler` and `CanShowHelpHandler` are declared as

```
static void ShowHelpHandler(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
static void CanShowHelpHandler(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

This will register Help command bound to F1 at all windows.

Comment: @Mohsan: sorry, have no experience with WinForms; please wait for other answers.